# Insert statement returns A value is required for bind parameter <x>

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, csv, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert a row from a CSV file into a Postgres database that lives on Heroku website, the code access the database, opens CSV file and access tha data, but also returns a InvalidRequestError.

The code fetches the data from the CSV file correctly, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

the data format is in CSV file:
1416949658,The Dark Is Rising,Susan Cooper,1973

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE books(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        isbn VARCHAR NOT NULL,                  
                title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        author_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        publish_year INTEGER NOT NULL

);
```

```
for isbn, title, author_name, publish_year in reader:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author_name, publish_year) VALUES (:isbn, :title, :author_name, :publish_year)",\
                {isbn: isbn, title: title, author_name: author_name, publish_year: publish_year})
    print(f"Added book {title} written by {author_name} with isbn {isbn} on year {publish_year}")
db.commit()
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A
>   value is required for bind parameter 'isbn' [SQL: INSERT INTO books
>   (isbn, title, author_name, publish_year) VALUES (%(isbn)s, %(title)s,
>   %(author_name)s, %(publish
>   _year)s);] [parameters: [{'1416949658': '1416949658', 'The Dark Is Rising': 'The Dark Is Rising', 'Susan Cooper': 'Susan Cooper', '
>   1973': '1973'}]]

As you see it fetches the data but returns an error still.

Comment: I think you need to quote the dictionary keys: `{'isbn': isbn, 'title': title, 'author_name': author_name,...`

Answer (score 0):

- To import the data from csv run the following snippet

```py
import csv
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


def main():
    f = open("books.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for isbn, title, author, year in reader:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author, year) VALUES (:isbn, :title, :author, :year)",
                   {"isbn": isbn, "title": title, "author": author, "year": year})
        print(
            f"Added book of ISBN {isbn} having Title: {title} written by  {author} in the year {year}.")
    db.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This should solve your problem. You are missing the `{"key": value}` format that is needed to be supplied for a dictionary in python.